# Spring DI for Repository (JAVA)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, inversion-of-control

I make a test Spring Controller application -> Service -> Repository

Controller->

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {


@Autowired
private ProductServiceImpl productService;

    @RequestMapping("/getAll")
    public List getAll(){
        return productService.getAll();
    }
}
```

Service ->

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements Services.ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;


    @Override
    public List<Product> getAll() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
   }
}
```

Repository ->

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {
}
```

Application ->

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("Repository")
@ComponentScan("com.lopamoko")
public class CloudliquidApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CloudliquidApplication.class, args);

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to do in the controller
@Autowired
private ProductServiceImpl productServiceImpl; - He swears that there is no bean for this. - I do in Application Bean - it starts swearing, that it can not now find a Bean for the ProductRepository (Interface) - when I call it from the Service. How do I make a bean for an interface?

Comment: try @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="org.my.pkg") // provide base package of @Repository annotated class.

Comment: @EnableJpaRepositories - already exist in Application class

Comment: @ДимаГуманов try changing 
`@Autowired
private ProductServiceImpl productService; `
to                                       
`@Autowired
private Services.ProductService productService;`

Comment: By the way, you don't need `@Repository` on Spring Data JPA classes (derived from `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository` interface) - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-spring-data-jpa-repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the value of `@EnableJpaRepositories` which is probably missleading, and it is pointing to the wrong package?. The value of `@EnableJpaRepositories` represents the base package to scan for repositories.

If ProductRepository lies withing "com.lopamoko", you can leave the value empty.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan("com.lopamoko")
public class CloudliquidApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CloudliquidApplication.class, args);

    String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        System.out.println(beanName);
    }
}
```

Because you already specified the package to scan inside of `@ComponentScan("com.lopamoko")`

If your Repository lies within different package, you need to specify the package as the value of `@EnableJpaRepositories`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.repository")
@ComponentScan("com.lopamoko")
public class CloudliquidApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CloudliquidApplication.class, args);

    String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        System.out.println(beanName);
    }
}
```

Do not forget also to anotate your Product entity with JPA annotation `@Entity`